# Spring Security Grails Plugin working with existing Database Schema?

Tags: grails, spring-security, legacy-database

I recently ran into a situation where I wanted to implement Grails + Spring Security over an existing database schema.  The Database already had a users table, a roles based table and the relationship roles+user table.    I am able to map the users domain to the existing schema.. but where I am running into problems is when trying to tie in the roles and user roles.

Any ideas?  Does this make sense or do I need to include more info?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the documentation here on how to configure alternate tables for the roles

http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/4%20Required%20and%20Optional%20Domain%20Classes.html#4.2%20Authority%20Class